# how to crop images left & right only for mobile devices

Tags: css

I'm totally new to CSS3 and I am having trouble with images...

In the desktop web it's working fine with big pictures and texts about 1/10 its height

but on mobile devices the images are too big to be displayed and the texts look so small since the screen is zoomed out.

So I want the picture to be cropped at sides keeping the height as original.

- I'm using bootstrap so it'd be better if there was a fancy way to deal it with bootstrap classes..

sorry for the easy and possibly duplicate question I couldn't find one though

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using bootstrap. there is a class in bootstrap.css called
**".img-responsive"**

I would suggest you to add this class to your **img** tag

Comment: But this one scales the width to match the window and scales down height proportionally. I want it to reserve the height and crop off the sides... It's only a background image so there's no big point in displaying it as a whole it just needs to fill some of the height for the text to be displayed upon.

Comment: Are you asking to edit background img of any div or body?